# Проблема со списком

Tags: python, python-3.x

Требуется получить список из N списков, состоящих из символов английского алфавита:

```
[[N], [N, N-1], [N, N-1, N-2], ... ]
```

Например, для N = 5 должен быть результат:

```
[['e'], ['e', 'd'], ['e', 'd', 'c'], ['e', 'd','c', 'b'], ['e', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'a']]
```

А получается:

```
[['e', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'a'], ['e', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'a'], ['e', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'a'], ['e', 'd','c', 'b', 'a'], ['e', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'a']]
```

Подскажите, в чем косяк.

```
size = int(input())

alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
alpha_list = list(alphabet)

symbols = []
first_symbols = []

for i in range (size-1, -1, -1):
    symbol = alpha_list[i]
    symbols.append(symbol)
    first_symbols.append(symbols)

print(first_symbols)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
n = 5
alphabet = list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')

print([alphabet[i:n][::-1] for i in range(n - 1, -1, -1)])
# [['e'], ['e', 'd'], ['e', 'd', 'c'], ['e', 'd', 'c', 'b'], ['e', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'a']]
```

Comment: круто, я чуть по другому решил сделать. Но этот вариант гораздо проще и лучше. Не буду свой выкладывать. Вам плюс.

Comment: @slippyk,  огромное спасибо! Шикарное решение! Сразу видно, питонист 80-го лвла! )